# Is the performance of using ruby block in Logstash conf worse over using other standard Logstash plugins?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

In the logstash configuration, A.B.C.D is an IP and I want to extract a part of it, like A.B.C. I have been acheiving this using regex matching in a ruby block using the following code :

```
    ruby {
    code => "event['Awesome_IP'] =event['Not_Awesome_IP'].match('\A\d{,3}.\d{,3}.\d{,3}').to_s;"
    }
```

However I have heard that the performance of the same isn't very good, when compared to doing, say, the following :

```
mutate {
    split => { "Awesome_IP" =>  "." }
}
mutate {
    remove_field => ["[Awesome_IP[3]"]
}
mutate {
    join => ["[Awesome_IP]", "."]
}
```

Can anyone point to some performance pointers, or some benchmarking tools that I can use to evaluate performance in the case? I am using this to parse logs of the order of a few millions a day. (Just need a performance comparison of the two methods).

Comment: You can perhaps start from this [script](https://gist.github.com/jsvd/a2613ea1ba00f02926a302781ca62f7b), which was used to compare grok filter performance in [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/do-you-grok-grok)

Comment: @baudsp It is about grok matching performance, however I am trying to compare the performance of ruby block, over other plugins. Also, my Ruby is not the best, so just as a side note, would be interesting to see a few pointers as to see how the script can be used to measure logstash performance. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The script I've linked is to check the performance of the grok plugin, which I though it would be possible to modify to check the performance of your two plugins. The modification would have required good Ruby, which I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at grok filter and do some benchmarks to check which approach performs better.

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok